# Using chrome for capybara, rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, rspec, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I spend more than 2 days trying to figure how to use google chrome for capybara but no luck:( Trying to test a form button. The test that has js: true is failing. I did install firefox because as far as I searched, even though I want to use chrome, I need to have firefox install on the computer then make chrome default.(Please correct me if I'm wrong) I also installed chromedriver. Used to get some timing errors that keeps firefox opening and closing for so long but I have came this far:

My rails_helper:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require "selenium-webdriver"
require 'rails_helper'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
 Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
 Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = '/Users/erincemer/Downloads/chromedriver'
end
(this is where I have chromedriver)
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.include CsvHelper
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end
  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end
  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

and my test is:

describe "visit clearance_batches#new" do

```
    it 'should get an error message when tries to find an item with empty string', js: true do
      visit '/clearance_batches/new'

      fill_in 'id_field', with: ""
      click_button 'find item'
      expect(page).to have_content('*Id can not be blank!')
    end
   end
```

and my failure is :

Failures:

```
  1) visit clearance_batches#new should get an error message when tries to find an item with empty string
     Failure/Error: visit '/clearance_batches/new'
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `needs_server?' for "/Users/erincemer/Downloads/chromedriver":String
```

I don't get where "needs_server?" is coming from , I dont have it anywhere in the app.

My test file is inside features folder. Adding

> :type => feature

(which I dont know what it's for) to my test doesn't change anything. I have another test that has

> visit '/clearance_batches/new'
>   without js: true

and that doesn't give any error so that route is correct. I tried to be as specific as possible. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block passed to `register_server` needs to return a Capybara::Driver::Base instance (which Capybara::Selenium::Driver derives from).  By setting `driver_path` after creating the instance your block is actually returning a string.  Either moving the `Chrome.driver_path` setting out of the block or swapping the order of the two lines inside the `register_driver` block will fix the issue you're having

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = '/Users/erincemer/Downloads/chromedriver'
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end
```

You don't need to install Firefox if you're going to use Chrome, just chromedriver.  If trying to use Firefox 48+ you need to install geckodriver.

Comment: Thanks, but both suggestions gave me this failure:                                  `Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
       unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary`
Now, 14 out of 21 tests are failing.

Comment: @EricdeSouza that's a different issue and sounds like chrome is not in your PATH

Comment: By saying 'Chrome', do we mean Google Chrome or chromdriver that I already installed? And how do I add chrome into my path?

Comment: Google Chrome - It needs to be somewhere the system will search for it by default, or add it's directory to the PATH in whatever shell setup scripts you are using - https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started

Comment: Thanks but I can't see anything that I haven't tried in the link.

Comment: @EricdeSouza  "ChromeDriver expects you to have Chrome installed in the default location for your platform." - Where do you have Chrome installed and what platform are you on?

Comment: Im little confused.The path Im using('/Users/erincemer/Downloads/chromedriver') is for chromedriver, not for Google Chrome. So, I need to provide the path of Google Chrome? Im using Mac and Google Chrome is installed on desktop, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: @EricdeSouza  Installed on desktop, or in /Applications like is standard on MacOS?  Selenium looks for chromedriver in your PATH, if you didn't install it in your PATH then you need to specify the location, which you've done  (if you had installed it with homebrew via `brew install chromedriver` it would be in your PATH and you wouldn't need to specify a location).  Then chromedriver needs to find Chrome, so it looks in the default location for the platform which on MacOS is in /Applications

Comment: @EricdeSouza You can override the Chrome location by passing options to chromedriver but it's easier to just install Chrome where expected (/Applications)

Comment: Ok got it:) I moved google chrome to applications from my desktop.